# "Дискурс о мужской эпиляции" или "дискурс мужской эпиляции"?

Tags: стилистика, переводы, дополнение

Название [научной публикации](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26907912):

> "I think gorilla-like back effusions of hair are rather a turn-off": 'Excessive hair' and male body hair (removal) discourse.

Мой упрощенный перевод:

> «Мне кажется, что когда из спины лезут волосы, словно у гориллы – это отталкивает»: 'лишние волосы' и дискурс мужской эпиляции

Можно ли сказать "дискурс о мужской эпиляции"?

Не уверен, как правильнее и красивее сказать. В статье приводятся три основных взгляда на проблему волосяного покрова на теле у мужчин - "удалять, нельзя оставлять" \ "удалять нельзя, оставлять" \ "привести в порядок и оставить". ^_^

Так как тут в скобках (removal), то придется и это учесть, и тут получается либо

> ... и дискурс о мужском оволосении и мужской эпиляции.

либо

> ... и дискурс мужского оволосения и мужской эпиляции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы серьезно собираетесь переводить английское discourse термином "дискурс", то дальше можете делать, что пожелаете - хуже уже не будет.

discourse - это речь, рассуждения, высказывания. Термин "дискурс" в русском языке имеет очень ограниченное научно-книжное и профессиональное применение и означает прежде всего "текст как предмет лингвистического исследования". Ну и еще несколько подобных и совсем редких значений.

Переведите как "речь" или как "рассуждения" - вопросы сами собой отпадут.
На самый край - "споры", "полемика", "дискуссия". Во всех случаях предложное управление очевидном. Если спорят авторы, а не оволосение.

Как вариант (можно править):
***Я думаю, что гориллоподобные мужские спины - отталкивающие. Высказывания о мужском оволосении и мужской эпиляции.***

(+)
*При вполне осмыленном переводе первой части, Вы попались на избитый ЛДП.*

Comment: Спасибо - я как раз сомневался в переводе слова "дискурс".. Возможно, при анализе высказываний на ту или иную тему, совокупность этих высказываний иногда все же называют "дискурс". В специализированных статьях часто заимствуют англоязычные слова. Пытаясь избежать "ложного друга переводчика", можно переусердствовать. Если написать "дискурс о мужской эпиляции", даже если это и окажется ЛДП, в принципе смысл будет понятен.

Comment: В Википедии пишут, что "Ди́скурс или диску́рс[1][2] (от фр. discours — речь, выступление) в общем смысле — речь, процессы языковой деятельности и предполагающие их системы понятий". Вроде бы вполне подходит под предмет исследования данной статьи.

Comment: "Таксономия дискурса базируется на нескольких автономных параметрах. Наиболее крупный из них — различие по модусу, или информационному каналу. Самые изученные модусы — устный и письменный." ([Фонд Ломоносов](http://www.lomonosov-fund.ru/enc/ru/encyclopedia:0127182:article)). Пока что оставлю "дискурс".. дискурс-анализ, дискурсивный анализ.

Comment: [Пример](http://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/sostoyanie-i-zadachi-izucheniya-veterinarnogo-diskursa): "Анализ **дискурса о домашних любимцах** в англоязычном ареале сегодня следует начинать с определения ключевого понятия: защитники животных, призывая к созданию нового языка о животных, настаивают на замене привычного слова «pet» сочетанием «companion animal»"